# Part of Thymeleaf fragment included only once

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf fragment like this

```
<div th:fragment="f1">
    <script src="x.js"></script>
    <div> ... </div>
</div>
```

The script part I want to include it only once, even though I will include `f1` more than once in the page.
What's the easiest/cleanest way to achieve this?

I can even split this fragment into two fragments and then the problem will be reduced on how to include a fragment only once in a page.

It can be somehow done if we'll be able to manipulate the request attributes from Thymeleaf. I understand that Thymeleaf if for rendering only, but a feature like this could be useful. Even to have something like include-once or if the included fragment has an id(or th:id) attribute, to include it only once.

Comment: I think it's impossible using one fragment. Can't you just divide it and have 2 fragments, one with script included always? Maybe if you explain better why do you want to have these elements in the same fragment it will be easier to find a suitable solution.

Comment: let's say that I want to include a fragment that display some info, but to do so a script must be included in the page too. Of course that script must be included only once, but the fragment can be included multiple times. I don't want to be forced to include two fragments, as this is prone to error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use #ids.

```
<div th:fragment="f1">
  <script src="x.js" th:if="${#ids.seq('f1.script.') == 'f1.script.1'}"></script>
  hello
</div>
```

or

```
<div th:fragment="f1">
  <script src="x.js" th:if="${#ids.next('f1.script.') == 'f1.script.1'}" th:id="${#ids.seq('f1.script.')}"></script>
  hello
</div>
```